# ABBYY OCR on Azure Cloud only supports blob storage in West Europe?

Tags: azure, ocr, abbyy

I want to use ABBYY on Microsoft Azure cloud, but in only shows 'West Europe' as the blob storage option. My bob storage is within the US, does this mean that my data should be transferred to blob storage within West Europe to get processed by ABBYY?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, at this moment it works this way. But ABBYY is going to have blob storage in Unites States. You can discuss it with ABBYY's managers using [the form on the website](http://ocrsdk.com/request/?purpose=buy?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_term=ABBYY-OCR-on-Azure%20Cloud-storage&utm_campaign=smm).

A little tip: you can use [ABBYY's forum](http://forum.ocrsdk.com/?purpose=buy?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_term=ABBYY-OCR-on-Azure%20Cloud-storage&utm_campaign=smm) for the qusetions about ABBYY's SDK products.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY.